# Where to save and read credential file for the DigitalOcean App Platform?

Tags: firebase, docker, firebase-security, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I created docker backend application that uses Firebase Admin SDK - https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#node.js_2.
At the startup, the application reads JSON file from somewhere.

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path/to/credentials_file.json"),
});
```

I want to deploy this application on the **DigitalOcean app platform**. Where I can save this credentials_file.json? Is it even supported for the DigitalOcean app platform?

NOTE:

- The application is a public docker image, so I can't put the file inside the image.

Answer (score 3):

A less well known way to initialize the SDK is to use the `cert` function. Then you can simply pass the config as a single line JSON string:

```js
import { cert, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";


initializeApp({
  credential: cert(JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_SDK_CONFIG)),
});
```

Comment: I did something similar in Go for a Heroku deployment.